# Почему не срабатывает if условие?

Tags: php

```php
var_dump($managerId);echo"<br>";
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    var_dump(intval($row['manager_id']));
    if(intval($row['manager_id'])===$managerId){break;}
    else{$managerId=false;}
}
```

Вывод:

Первый `var_dump()`: **int(6)**

В цикле:

```
int(2) int(3) int(4) int(5) int(6) int(7) int(8) int(9) int(10) int(11) int(12) int(13) int(33) int(125) int(128)
```

Я вижу совпадение. Почему не срабатывает условие в `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в `else` он не попадает в `if` потому что вы присваиваете `$managerId` значение `false`

```
var_dump($managerId);echo"<br>";
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    var_dump(intval($row['manager_id']));
    if(intval($row['manager_id'])===$managerId){break;}
    else{$managerId=false;} 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не до вардампил(

Comment: Чем код в ответе отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: К этому вопросу нельзя дать конкретный ответ